# Javascript Crypto AES decrypt

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, base64, cryptojs

This is the crypto AES encryption code in server side. How can I `decrypt in javascript`. I can't find any decryption logic having both iv and key with padding.

```
public static String encrypt(String key, String initVector, String value) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("l353b3l3jk3bk3j3".getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("2353c3l3jk3bk3j8".getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            System.out.println("encrypted string: " + Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted));

            return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Attempt the problem yourself and ask about a specific issue you are having.  StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/) in the following way:

```
var decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherText, CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key), 
{
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 //default
});
console.log('Decrypted Data: ' + decrypted);
```

PKCS5 is not supported by this library but you should not be using it as it was designed for DES rather than AES. However if you dont want to change it then you can still use PKCS7 for decryption and it will work because the difference is in the block size both paddings supports. PKCS5 only works with 8-byte blocks whereas PKCS7 works with block sizes betwheen 1 and 255 bytes. DES uses block size of 8 bytes.

Comment: what about the key and iv

Comment: Downvoted for ECB mode.  And AES is a 128 bit block size, not 64.

Comment: Note that the java padding mode `PKCS5PADDING` is really PKCS7 padding after all.